# Single quotes in variable in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a condition where user will pass comma separated values like

```
0071061386,0071061387
```

it will be passed to a variable which will feed the values into a dynamic query with two single quotes.

passed by user

```
declare @s nvarchar(max) = '0071061386,0071061387'
```

it should be like after converting the user values so that I can pass the values into dynamic query

```
declare @s nvarchar(max) = '''0071061386'',''0071061387'''
```

Comment: Rather than continuing down this route, can you not arrange for the user to pass the data to you using a more appropriate data type, i.e. one *designed* to hold multiple values, such as a table-valued parameter or the XML type?

Comment: That's another [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/). You **DON'T** want the user to pass CSVs and you **DON'T** want to create any kind of dynamic query with them. If you want to send multiple values to a query, use a table type, or use SqlBulkCopy to insert rows in bulk.

Comment: So, the user enters `1,1);Drop Table Orders;--`. Your query happily passes this to the dynamic query which sees a *batch* of statements, one inserting a record, the next dropping a table. Anything after the drop statement gets ignored as a comment.

Comment: PS if you insist on using CSVs, at least use `STRING_SPLIT` to split the string and return a table of rows. Use the table in a proper query instead of using string concatenation to create a "dynamic" query

Comment: PPS hackers **search SO** and similar sites for such bad practices because they know, these *will* appear in production at some point. Finding out where a programmer works and who his company's clients are is just a couple of google searches. It doesn't have to be precise either - enough to generate a list of target companies.

Answer (score 2):

A simple replace with probably do the trick here, but I beleive this to be an [XYProblem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps you better explain the problem leading you to go this path in the first place.

```
declare @s nvarchar(max) = '0071061386,0071061387'

SELECT '''''' + REPLACE(@s, ',', ''''',''''') + ''''''
```

Result:

```
''0071061386'',''0071061387''
```

Comment: Thanks It worked
DECLARE @T nvarchar(max) = '0071061386,0071061387'
--SELECT ''''+ replace(@S,',',''',''') +''''
DECLARE @U NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT ''''+ replace(@T,',',''',''') +'''')
select @U

Comment: @AshishMandal as Zohar already mentioned, that's an answer but you are asking the wrong question. *Why* do you pass CSVs when you can pass a list of values?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  DECLARE @S NVARCHAR(MAX) = '0071061386,0071061387'
  SELECT REPLACE(''''''''+@S+'''''''',',',''''',''''')
```

Comment: And then the user enters `1,1);Drop Table Orders;--`. Even though this answers the question, what the user asks is how to shoot his own foot.

Comment: Thanks it works
DECLARE @T nvarchar(max) = '0071061386,0071061387'
--SELECT ''''+ replace(@S,',',''',''') +''''
DECLARE @U NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT ''''+ replace(@T,',',''',''') +'''')
select @U

Comment: @AshishMandal congratulations, you've been breeched. Legal wants a word. *Explain your actual problem*, not the hack you tried instead of a fix

Comment: @AshishMandal you should know that hackers search SO and similar sites for such bad practices because they know, these *will* appear in production at some point. Finding out where a programmer works and who his company's clients are is just a couple of google searches. It doesn't have to be precise either